# Dynamic Pivot query exceeds maximum length of varchar (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have been trying to convert rows to columns in SQL.

Just like this:

```
|*Name*|*Permissions*|
|App1  |Permission 1 |
|App1  |Permission 2 |
|App1  |Permission 3 |
|App2  |Permission 1 |
|App2  |Permission 2 |
|App2  |Permission 3 |
```

to this:

```
|*Name*|*Permission1*|*Permission2*|*Permission3*|
|App1  |Permission 1 |Permission 2 |Permission 3 |
|App2  |Permission 1 |Permission 2 |Permission 3 |
```

Therefore I have been using something like this code for generating the query dynamically

```
declare @permission_id as VARCHAR(7);
declare @counter as int;
declare @query as VARCHAR(MAX);
declare @name as VARCHAR(15);

set @permission_id = 'permission_';
set @query = 'SELECT a.title, ';
set @counter = 0;

WHILE @counter < 3
BEGIN
    PRINT @counter;
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    SET @name = (SELECT CONCAT(@permission_id, @counter));
    SET @query = @query + ' select max(case when seqnum = '
    SET @query = (SELECT CONCAT(@query, @counter))
    SET @query = @query + ' then a.permission end) as '
    SET @query = (SELECT CONCAT(@query, @name))

END
```

which generates a query like this:

```
select a.name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then a.permission end) as permission_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then a.permission end) as permission_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then a.permission end) as permission_3
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.name order by a.name) as seqnum
      from apps a
     ) a
group by a.name;
```

The result is working fine for up to 120 Permissions, because that is the point where the query exceeds the max length of varchar.

I have not found a solution for dynamic pivot-ing without concating a query yet, and neither I did find a solution for a longer query.

That's why I am asking this question.

Is there a way for dynamic pivot without CONCAT-ing a query or is there something I can use instead of varchar?

Thank you!

Comment: Random question: Did you get this SQL from one of Gordon Linoff's answers?  The code looks just like the way he writes it.

Comment: Yes I did, at least more or less. You can look it up here if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183730/how-to-convert-rows-to-new-columns-in-m-to-n-relation-ship-table

Comment: I suppose you could break the query up into chunks? 1-100 would be `@querypart1`, 2-200 would be `@querypart2` etc.  But ultimately, is this sql server?  I thought varchar(max) is like 2Gb.  I don't see how 120 would hit a varchar(max) limit.

Comment: Actually, something else I think is going on.  You're showing `@permission_id as VARCHAR(7)` but then you can't set it to `'permission_'`.  Maybe you should show more of your actual code with the actual data types.

Comment: I put your code in my sql server and I did not exceed any variable limits when using `WHILE @counter < 7000`

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not mention, I am working with Microsoft SQL Server, and the maxlen of a varchar there is 8000 characters.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to split the query up as it is in the select statement.